# How to assign variable and use sed to replace contents of configuration file in Dockerfile?

Tags: sed, environment-variables, docker

I am running a `Dockerfile`, but, am encountering a problem when I assign a variable for modifying `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, with its string content-"PRIVATEIP".

`Dockerfile` generates an error and stops. Because I have no idea about assigning a variable with `sed` to modify the string content in a specific file.

```
RUN IP=$(cat /root/ip_variable) | sed -i -r "s/PRIVATEIP/${IP}/g" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
 ---> Running in 1e78ef4318ab
```

If there are any alternative methods to handle this please let me know.

===========================================================================

Add more explanation for an alternative method as below on 2018/July 11:

I add some command lines on Dockerfile. The purpose is same as before. I alternatively use echo to write a script as below. But, it's weird. Why does the fellow character "/" after "s" on "sed" this command get missed? (If there are any methods to add high light or mark on the character within the output of the code, I thanks to you.) If this matter is resolved, I thinks I am able to close this issues.

```
Step 64/73 : RUN echo "#!/bin/bash\nexport PRIVATEIP=$(cat /home/ip_variable)\nsed -i -r \"s/\bPRIVATEIP\b/\${PRIVATEIP}/g\" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local\nsed -i -r \"s/\bPRIVATEIP\b/\${PRIVATEIP}/g\" /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts" > /home/start_script.sh
 ---> Running in bbff59f82475
Removing intermediate container bbff59f82475
 ---> 0068d9d600ff
Step 65/73 : RUN cat /home/ip_variable
 ---> Running in faeb4bb1a6ba
172.17.0.2/16
Removing intermediate container faeb4bb1a6ba
 ---> f6cc35fd01e5
Step 66/73 : RUN cat /home/start_script.sh
 ---> Running in 95a5ef3b7d23
#!/bin/bash
export PRIVATEIP=172.17.0.2/16
sed -i -r "sPRIVATEI/${PRIVATEIP}/g" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
sed -i -r "sPRIVATEI/${PRIVATEIP}/g" /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
Removing intermediate container 95a5ef3b7d23
 ---> 6720e7c01efc
Step 67/73 : RUN chmod 755 /home/start_script.sh
 ---> Running in d8ab5e04a846
Removing intermediate container d8ab5e04a846
 ---> decb9e147db9
Step 68/73 : RUN sh /home/start_script.sh
 ---> Running in fc86000f9a2f
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s'
The command '/bin/sh -c sh /home/start_script.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Can you please share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: a wild guess, probably you should use `;` instead of `|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all. 
I the matter is on delimiter. I change "/" to be ":" and get it worked. I post the result in here. In "Step 65/78", I print the script content and "Step 67/78" run the script well. Thanks @xenoid and @Kusalananda.

```
Step 63/78 : RUN echo "#!/bin/sh -x\nsed -i 's:PRIVATEIP:'"$(cat /home/ip_variable)"':g' /etc/fail2ban/jail.local\nsed -i 's:PRIVATEIP:'"$(cat /home/ip_variable)"':g' /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts" > /home/ip_change_script.sh
 ---> Running in 251d6741c37e
Removing intermediate container 251d6741c37e
 ---> 95c4aa62d74a
Step 64/78 : RUN cat /home/ip_variable
 ---> Running in 8825ef517fb8
172.17.0.2/16
Removing intermediate container 8825ef517fb8
 ---> 39672eb7021d
Step 65/78 : RUN cat /home/ip_change_script.sh
 ---> Running in 2161051ee4cf
#!/bin/sh -x
sed -i 's:PRIVATEIP:'172.17.0.2/16':g' /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
sed -i 's:PRIVATEIP:'172.17.0.2/16':g' /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
Removing intermediate container 2161051ee4cf
 ---> 407ccc7106f7
Step 66/78 : RUN chmod 755 /home/ip_change_script.sh
 ---> Running in 0f6ca7f78ba8
Removing intermediate container 0f6ca7f78ba8
 ---> 250afb327db0
Step 67/78 : RUN sh /home/ip_change_script.sh
 ---> Running in 4b209e18854b
Removing intermediate container 4b209e18854b
 ---> d45d024e1359
Step 68/78 : RUN touch /home/service_boot.log
 ---> Running in 3548dc45f466
Removing intermediate container 3548dc45f466
 ---> 587527e18ab2
Step 69/78 : RUN cat /home/service_boot.log
 ---> Running in b068b00cd584
Removing intermediate container b068b00cd584
 ---> 3183e6b281ed
Step 70/78 : COPY boot_service.sh /home/boot_service.sh
 ---> 9a73dd4fd87d
Step 71/78 : RUN chmod 755 /home/boot_service.sh
 ---> Running in 2f226574e28d
Removing intermediate container 2f226574e28d
 ---> 8a0c14218e1b
Step 72/78 : RUN cat /home/boot_service.sh
 ---> Running in 5fa64827b6dd
```

Comment: Funny, `:` or `~` didn't work for me but `|` worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
FROM alpine

COPY ipaddr /ipaddr
COPY ipconf /ipconf
RUN export IPADDR=$(cat /ipaddr) ; sed -i -r "s/IPADDR/${IPADDR}/g" /ipconf
CMD cat /ipconf
```

With ipconf & ipaddr

```
IP address is IPADDR

1.2.3.4
```

Then:

```
>docker build -t dynchange .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine
---> 3fd9065eaf02
Step 2/5 : COPY ipaddr /ipaddr
---> Using cache
---> 1828c3157d41
Step 3/5 : COPY ipconf /ipconf
---> 4f43e88e4425
Step 4/5 : RUN export IPADDR=$(cat /ipaddr) ;  sed -i -r "s/IPADDR/${IPADDR}/g" /ipconf
---> Running in 722c3d3d9d9e
Removing intermediate container 722c3d3d9d9e
---> 32e31198b70a
Step 5/5 : CMD cat /ipconf
---> Running in 72ea59543a7f
Removing intermediate container 72ea59543a7f
---> 73f8a50d650a
Successfully built 73f8a50d650a
Successfully tagged dynchange:latest

>docker run --rm dynchange
IP address is 1.2.3.4
```

However, this is exactly how I would not do it.  A better way is to use a build arg:

```
FROM alpine

COPY ipconf /ipconf
ARG IPADDR
RUN sed -i -r "s/IPADDR/${IPADDR}/g" /ipconf
CMD cat /ipconf
```

Then:

```
>docker build -t dynchange --build-arg IPADDR=4.5.6.7  .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine
---> 3fd9065eaf02
Step 2/5 : COPY ipconf /ipconf
---> Using cache
---> f5ac88ee48d5
Step 3/5 : ARG IPADDR
---> Running in 58d972e14660
Removing intermediate container 58d972e14660
---> fc3de48160c6
Step 4/5 : RUN sed -i -r "s/IPADDR/${IPADDR}/g" /ipconf
---> Running in 8ec855697510
Removing intermediate container 8ec855697510
---> 67e946559316
Step 5/5 : CMD cat /ipconf
---> Running in a5260c593c02
Removing intermediate container a5260c593c02
---> 567a31a517d1
Successfully built 567a31a517d1
Successfully tagged dynchange:latest

>docker run --rm dynchange
IP address is 4.5.6.7
```

However I'm not even sure this is the right solution. I would either:

- build the configuration file outside of the container, and create/replace it with a `COPY`. This gives full control on its contents.
- pass that IP address as a parameter when the container is run (environment variable or else), so you have one single container image that can be used in several environments. The `CMD` or`ENTRYPOINT` can be script that patches the file before calling the main command. You can also pass the configuration file as a VOLUME (this can avoid issues if CMD is run as an application user and patching the config requires root privileges).

Answer (score 2):

An assignment does not produce output and it's therefore pointless to pipe it to another process.

Instead, use `;` to divide the pipeline inte two sequential commands:

```
IP=$(cat /root/ip_variable); sed -i "s/PRIVATEIP/$IP/g" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

I'm unfamiliar with Docker and it's `RUN` command.  If it only takes a *single* command, then use

```
RUN sh -c 'IP=$(cat /root/ip_variable); sed -i "s/PRIVATEIP/$IP/g" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local'
```

or

```
RUN sed -i "s/PRIVATEIP/$(cat /root/ip_variable)/g" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it is not working. I writed the command line like yours. 
I add the command line to `Dockerfile`. It is `RUN echo "#/bin/bash\nIP=$(cat /root/ip_variable)\ndeclare -x IP=\$IP" > /root/    script.sh` and `RUN /bin/bash /root/script.sh`. But, I also use `RUN export` to check the result. There isn't any variable set. 
Why I have to use /bin/bash due to the default as `sh` not `bash`. The `sh` won't run `declare`. So, I use a script to drive it.

Comment: @jefferyear That's no the command I have in my question.